# How to migrate from md5 to sha256 encryption

Tags: encryption, md5, sha256

I have a database with thousands of md5 encrypted passwords and I need to migrate to sha256. What is the safest way to do this by keeping the old passwords with md5 access and the new one with sha256 encryption? Thanks.

Comment: While you are at it, you might want to migrate to PBKDF2 and a salt. You would have to store the salt and the PBKDF2 result instead of the password. SHA-256 (which is a secure hash, not a type of encryption) is still succeptible to rainbow tables and the like.

Comment: Interesting! Is there any vbscript (classic asp) -based implementation of PBKDF2 with salt?

Comment: With the help of google I learned that I can use a randomly generated string for each user as a salt. To check if the password supplied by a user is valid, I would combine the password supplied with the salt, take the hash, and compare it with the hash stored in the database, right?. My question is: a salt can be a md5 encrypted string?

Comment: No, the salt should be random generated, and at least 8 bytes, stored together with the value. PBKDF2 is a crypto algorithm that takes a salt, a password, performs <iteration> count of hashing, and then returns a configurable number of "key" bytes. I don't know VBScript I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok. Since I do not have a vbscript-based implementation of PBKDF2, is there any problem if I hash as follows: **sha256(pwd & md5(salt))** or **sha256(pwd & sha256(salt))** or should I really use **sha256(pwd & salt)**? Thanks!

Comment: sha256(salt | pwd) would be most common, where | is the concatenation operator. Don't forget, sha256 already outputs a fixed length byte array. Do use a random salt per password. If you are paranoid, you may extend the salt with a static value you keep in code, which can act as kind of a secret key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively to creating a new column for the sha256 you can use the existing column for both. Because sha256 hashes are much longer than md5 hashes you can detect the hash algorithm by looking at the length of the hash.

Comment: I thought that too. Just had doubts about safety.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, use PBKDF2 or bcrypt. Plain SHA-2 is too fast.

If you can't use either of them, then you should at least iterate SHA-256 a couple of thousand times to slow down a password guessing attack:

```
var hash = SHA256(SHA256(salt)+password)
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
   hash = SHA256(hash);
return hash;
```

Remember that every user needs to have a different salt, which is usually stored alongside the password hash. A per-application salt is not enough.

---

For upgrading I'd use the old hash as input to the new function. That way existing hashes gain most of the security increase of the upgrade without requiring the user to login. Don't keep the old MD5 hashes around.

Then on the first login of each user, upgrade his hash to a clean new hash that doesn't use MD5 anymore.

Comment: If you are given a hash, it's still difficult to find the corresponding string that generates that hash, even with MD5. Hashes are typically cracked using reverse lookup tables or brute force whose chances are decreasing rapidly by adding new letters to the input, so concatenating a long random salt to the password is already enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a new column for the sha256 hash. That way you can just check the new column for null on login and save the new hash when you have access to the plaintext password.